# Cant install Tensorflow object detection API (Python)

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I have found instructions on installations but despite setting sys path it gives me error saying  `No such file or directory: 'content/drive/MyDrive/TensorFlow/models/research'`
This is my entire code from cloning repository to setting path:

```
%cd /content/drive/My Drive/Tensorflow
!git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

!apt-get install protobuf-compiler python-lxml python-pil
!pip install Cython pandas tf-slim lvis

%cd /content/drive/My Drive/Tensorflow/models/research
!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

import os
import sys


os.environ['PYTHONPATH']+=":/content/drive/MyDrive/TensorFlow/models"

sys.path.append("/content/drive/MyDrive/TensorFlow/models/research")
sys.path.append('/content/drive/MyDrive/TensorFlow/models/research/slim')
print("done")
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use the object detection API by installing all the required packages is by following the instructions given in the official repo [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md) for version 2.x and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1.md) for Tensorflow version 1.x

Once you finish installing and successfully run all tests using the above links(s), you can use the documentation [here](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to learn how to use it to train or test on your own dataset

Comment: Everything worked fine. But just where do  i have to copy this  "!cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py" since it should be like this "!cp source destination" so one of them is missing.

Comment: If you look closely, the command is `cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .`. There is a `.` after `setup.py` at the end. The `.` indicates the current directory. You should be executing these commands from the `models/research` directory as mentioned, and hence as a result, `setup.py` will be copied to the `models/research` directory

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations. I have already solved the problem)

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the tick button if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Yeah for sure, I have already done that but since I have less than 10 reputation It will be considered after I am over 10 reputation)